# Facebook manage_groups permission

Tags: php, api, permissions, facebook-opengraph

Is there any update on the ability to manage Facebook groups through the OpenGraph API. I am trying to delete members from my group using the API but I need the manage_groups permission.

Whenever I try to add it I get an API error stating it doesn't recognize it.

Has anyone had any success getting this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the permission "user_groups" and in automatically grant the manage_groups permission

user_groups permission to retrieve any groups that the session user is a member of.
The user_managed_groups permission can be used to read the group content for a group in which the user is an admin. This permission also allows the app to post as the user in the group if the app is also granted the publish_actions permission.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/group

The bad new is that faceboook will request you a submit a review and
it doesnt allow that permission for almost anyone platform. I made an web app with PHP and when i sent the review they refuse that permission with following answer:

The user_groups permission is only granted for apps building a Facebook-branded client on platforms where Facebook is not already available.
For example, Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In addition, Web, Desktop, in-car and TV apps will not be granted this permission.